# Registro de usuario con Devise API only: 422 Unprocessable Content: "User couldn't be created successfully."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Estoy creando una API en rails 7, usando devise y devise-jwt, e intento registrar un nuevo usuario mediante devise registrations, pero me da un error de unprocessable entity, donde el campo email y contraseña no pueden estar en blanco, pero en mi body de la petición los estoy pasando bien, y no entiendo por qué este error.

Aquí la migración para Users usando devise:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :firstname, null: false
      t.string :lastname, null: false
      t.string :gender, null: false
      t.date :birthdate, null: false
      t.string :phonenumber, null: false
      t.string :address, null: false
      t.string :roles, array: true, default: ['general']

      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

El archivo routes.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get '/current_user', to: 'current_user#index'
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'api/v1/users/sessions',
        registrations: 'api/v1/users/registrations'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

El ApplicationController

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password,
                                      :password_confirmation, :roles, :birthdate, :gender, :phonenumber])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password,
                                                              :password_confirmation, :roles, :birthdate,
                                                              :gender, :phonenumber])

  end

end
```

El RegistrationController:

```
module Api::V1
  class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    include RackSessionsFix
    respond_to :json

    protected

    def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})

      register_sucess(resource) && return if resource.persisted?

      register_failed(resource)

    end

    private

    def register_success(resource)
      render json: {
        status: {code: 200, message: 'Signed up successfully.'},
        data: UserSerializer.new(resource).serializable_hash[:data][:attributes]
      }
    end

    def register_failed(resource)
      render json: {
          status: {message: "User couldn't be created successfully. #{resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"}
        }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end
end
```

Y mi body de la petición http es el siguiente:

```
{
  "user": {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "password_confirmation": "123456789",
    "birthdate": "1997-11-26",
    "phonenumber": "12345567345",
    "address": "my address",
    "roles": ["general"]
  }
}
```

Nuevamente, el error que me da es:
422 Unprocessable Content

```
{
  "status": {
    "message": "User couldn't be created successfully. Email can't be blank and Password can't be blank"
  }
}
```

Estoy usando ruby 3.1.2 y rails 7.1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Ya hace unos años que no uso devise, pero revisando el [código del controlador de registro de devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L137), es `sign_up` lo que espera y no `user`. Deberías mandar desde el cliente de la API, algo como:

```
{
  "sign_up": {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "password_confirmation": "123456789",
    "birthdate": "1997-11-26",
    "phonenumber": "12345567345",
    "address": "my address",
    "roles": ["general"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Me sigue dando 422 unprocessable entity. Lo extraño es que aun cambiando el body, siempre da ese error. Si hago un binding.pry en el método respond_with, y ejecuto request.body.read, me imprime el body correctamente, pero por alguna razón es como si no se estuviese pasando el body a la creación del user. El código lo hice según unos videos de youtube de cómo hacer una API usando devise y devise-jwt, pero no entiendo cuál es el error.